# Proper way to combine these base templates in Django?

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to organize my Django templates in an intuitive fashion but I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have a base template that everything derives from which includes blocks for CSS files, JS files, etc. I also have a template that is used by all forms which includes blocks for fields, etc.

Now I am adding a "minimal" template that will serve as a base template for "minimal" pages. One small problem: I need to derive from the form template as well.

Here's a map to help explain what's going on:

[image]

At first I thought I could fix this by making the form an `include`-ed template. This has one really serious drawback: I can't override a `{% block %}` in the form template.

So how can I create a template (`minimal_form.html`) that includes blocks from both `minimal.html` and `form.html` and still be able to override the blocks in either template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different strategy is to do something like pass a context variable, `base_template = 'minimal.html'` from your view (or a context processor), and reference that in `form.html` like so:

```
{% extends base_template %}
```